# Change 'Show location of pointer when I press the Ctrl key' Windows setting from code

Tags: c#, winapi, mouse

How to change the 'Windows mouse checkBox' configuration 'Show location of pointer when I press the Ctrl key' from code (.net)? As described manually at this webpage?

https://mcmw.abilitynet.org.uk/windows-7-and-8-finding-your-mouse-pointer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`SystemParametersInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx) WinAPI function with the `SPI_SETMOUSESONAR` command to enable or disable mouse sonar (as this feature is called in WinAPI terms)

```
private void buttonEnableMouseSonar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetMouseSonarEnabled(true);
}

private void buttonDisableMouseSonar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetMouseSonarEnabled(false);
}


[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, uint pvParam, uint fWinIni);

private void SetMouseSonarEnabled(bool enable)
{
    const uint SPI_SETMOUSESONAR = 0x101D;
    const uint SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
    const uint SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 0x02;

    if(!SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESONAR, 0, (uint)(enable ? 1 : 0), SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE))
    {
        throw new Win32Exception();
    }
}
```

To use WinAPI functions from managed .net code, you use a functionality called "p/invoke".

- [MSDN documentation on P/Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-call-native-dlls-from-managed-code-using-pinvoke)
- [pinvoke.net - Useful resource with ready to copy & paste definitions for WinAPI functions](http://pinvoke.net)

---

VB.net version:

```
Private Sub buttonEnableMouseSonar_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SetMouseSonarEnabled(True)
End Sub

Private Sub buttonDisableMouseSonar_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    SetMouseSonarEnabled(False)
End Sub

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function SystemParametersInfo(ByVal uiAction As UInteger, ByVal uiParam As UInteger, ByVal pvParam As UInteger, ByVal fWinIni As UInteger) As Boolean
End Function


Private Sub SetMouseSonarEnabled(ByVal enable As Boolean)
    Const SPI_SETMOUSESONAR As UInteger = 4125
    Const SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE As UInteger = 1
    Const SPIF_SENDCHANGE As UInteger = 2
    If Not SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESONAR, 0, CUInt((If(enable, 1, 0))), SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE Or SPIF_SENDCHANGE) Then
        Throw New Win32Exception()
    End If
End Sub
```